# Gulp dest.on is not a function

Tags: gulp

I'm getting that annoying **dest.on error** on my gulp task for **optimizing images** using `gulp-imagemin`. I have a somewhat uncommon set up going here, using `gulp-load-plugins` in order to have all my tasks separate from the actual gulpfile.

On the task in question I'm requiring:

```
"gulp-imagemin": "^3.0.1",
"gulp-util": "^3.0.7",
```

And the idea is to log a message when the images are done for each of the streams, `gulp.dest()` doesn't seem to like something about my `gutil.log()` method:

```
module.exports = function(gulp, plugins, config) {

  return function()
  {
    var stream =
        // Optimize Images for Version A //
        gulp.src(config.assetsDir + '/a/images/*')
            .pipe(plugins.util.log('Hello'))
            .pipe(plugins.imagemin({
                progressive: true,
                optimizationLevel: 7,
                svgoPlugins: [{removeViewBox: false}],
                use: [plugins.pngquant()]
            }))
            .pipe(gulp.dest(config.publicDir + 'images/a/'))

        // Optimize Images for Version B //
        gulp.src(config.assetsDir + '/b/images/*')
            .pipe(plugins.imagemin({
                progressive: true,
                optimizationLevel: 7,
                svgoPlugins: [{removeViewBox: false}],
                use: [plugins.pngquant()]
            }))
            .pipe(gulp.dest(config.publicDir + 'images/b/'))
            .pipe(plugins.util.log("Task Done!"))
  }
};
```

The problem appears to be on the final line there, I'm sending in the dependency for `gutil` through my plugins object and then referencing it and calling it's `log()` method. It works fine without the log, what am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Things like `gulp.dest()` and plugins  like `imagemin()` return [`stream.Transform` objects](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_transform). Only those you can pass to `.pipe()`.

`gutil.log()` on other hand doesn't return a `stream.Transform` and therefore can't be passed to `.pipe()`.

If you still want to use it from within a stream you will have to listen for one of the events that are exposed by [node.js streams](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html), for example the [`'data'` event](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_data) (called for each file):

```
gulp.src(config.assetsDir + '/a/images/*')
  .on('data', function() { plugins.util.log('Hello'); })
```

Or the [`'end'` event](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_end) (called when a stream is done):

```
  .pipe(gulp.dest(config.publicDir + 'images/b/'))
  .on('end', function() { plugins.util.log("Task Done!") });
```